# Can't copy data from S3 to Redshift due to incompatible Parquet schema

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, parquet

This is the schema from my parquet file, that I'm trying to upload to Redshift.

```
Column Name: id, Data Type: int64
Column Name: eventtime, Data Type: string
Column Name: data, Data Type: null
Column Name: eventtype, Data Type: int64
Column Name: userid, Data Type: double
Column Name: ipaddress, Data Type: string
Column Name: sessionid, Data Type: string
Column Name: identity, Data Type: null
Column Name: _mage_created_at, Data Type: string
Column Name: _mage_updated_at, Data Type: string
```

And table in Redshift

```
CREATE TABLE userlogs (
    id int8,
    eventtime VARCHAR(255),
    data INTEGER,
    eventtype int8,
    userid DOUBLE PRECISION,
    ipaddress VARCHAR(255),
    sessionid VARCHAR(255),
    "identity" VARCHAR(255),
    _mage_created_at VARCHAR(255),
    _mage_updated_at VARCHAR(255),
    unique (id)) 
    SORTKEY (id);
```

And I get this error

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Spectrum Scan Error
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Spectrum Scan Error
  code:      15007
  context:   File 'https://s3.userlogs.parquet' has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 's3://userlogs.parquet.identity'. Column type: VARCHAR, Parquet schema:
optional 
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Is it the "identity" in quotation that makes the problems?

Comment: No. I'd look at "Column Name: identity, Data Type: null" in your parquet file as the likely cause.